# Google Wallet in app transaction between users

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-pay

Can you use Google Wallet to facilitate transactions between users of your app, where they pay eachother for the exchange of digital products, while the app takes out a small % out of that transaction? Also, would the 30% fee apply and where?

Answer (score 0):

Beside of being the only allowed payment method in Google Play, wallet is also yet another billing platform. It can't be used to proceed directly payments between users, but can be used to transfer funds to your company, and probably to transfer funds from your company to your users. For out of Google Play they use much lower cut than 30%